# unity google play app signing issue and keystore

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, signing, google-play-console

I have a unity game on the play store that I published a couple months ago. Today I tried to upload a new apk to the play console and got this error.

```
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.
```

From what I have read from other posts, this is an issue with the keystore in unity. When i went to the keystore settings, there is nothing selected. The only keystore on my computer is debug.keystore which i believe is not really a valid keystore. I have downloaded the app signing cert from the play console but that cant be used as a keystore. I am confused as to what to do now. Should i create a new keystore? my assumption is that it has to be the same keystore that was used before (even though i don't recall ever making one?). I also assume that if i did make one, it would be in my project directory somewhere, which its not. I know this has been asked before but im still confused. A lot of people are saying that there is nothing to do other than reupload the app. Others are saying that there is some way to update the play console signing to work with a new keystore?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem myself, and I'm sad to inform you that when you lose your Unity keystore, the only solution is to create a new keystore, and upload a new instance of the app on Google Play, as it will not accept an APK signed with a different key as update.

Always keep your keys and respective passwords stored in safe places, with backups for emergecies.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When did this happen to you? Some posts were saying with an update in 2017 some time, its possible but never really explained how. Random follow up question: If i delete the current game from the play store, does that package name become available? I believe it does not but just curious.

Comment: It was in 2017, but not sure when. I will do some research and come back to you if I find anything :)

Answer (score 2):

If your app uses Google Play app signing then Google support can help you change your upload key. Otherwise there is nothing you can do but republish your app. A good reason to use Google Play app signing. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Comment: That is similar to what i was finding as i was researching. On the play console, when i go to app signing, it says "Google Play App Signing is enabled for this app" so Im hoping they can do something to help. Have you gone through this process?

Comment: I have created a new keystore and submitted it for google to update. Hopefully this works.